# Accessing hash values by methods vs like in array in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a hash like this:

```
h = { "key1" => { "key2" => "value"}, "key3" => "value3"}
```

If I try to access `h.key1` it won't let me, but if I do `h["key1"]` it will.

But when I use the session hash, I can write the following code without getting an error:

```
@session = session["omniauth"] 
@session.data
```

When can I access the keys by methods and when like an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **only** access hash values with `h["key1"]` method (without using other modifiers).

The reason why `@session.data` works is that `@session` is not an instance of `Hash`, but its an instance of `OmniAuth::AuthHash` which supports both methods to access values.

So it depends on a type of an object you are working with.

Comment: Ah I thought its the same. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can access hash key by dot notation with the help of OpenStruct

```
require 'ostruct'
h = { "key1" => { "key2" => "value"}, "key3" => "value3"}
open_struct = OpenStruct.new(h)
p open_struct.key1
```

I hope It may help you to solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are able to access key-value from the session object is that someone has defined the method `[]` on it.

If you wanted to access h.key1 on your hash, use OpenStruct:

```
h = OpenStruct({ "key1" => { "key2" => "value"}, "key3" => "value3"})
```

This would return the following results:

```
h.key1 # { "key2" => "value }
h.key3 # "value3"
```